# How to decorate all functions of a class without typing it over and over for each method?

Tags: python, class, decorator, wrapper

Lets say my class has many methods, and I want to apply my decorator on each one of them, later when I add new methods, I want the same decorator to be applied, but I don't want to write `@mydecorator` above the method declaration all the time.

If I look into `__call__` is that the right way to go?

---

I'd like to show this way, which is a similar solution to my problem for anybody finding this question later, using a mixin as mentioned in the comments.

```
class WrapinMixin(object):
    def __call__(self, hey, you, *args):
        print 'entering', hey, you, repr(args)
        try:
            ret = getattr(self, hey)(you, *args)
            return ret
        except:
            ret = str(e)
            raise
        finally:
            print 'leaving', hey, repr(ret)
```

Then you can in another

```
class Wrapmymethodsaround(WrapinMixin): 
    def __call__:
         return super(Wrapmymethodsaround, self).__call__(hey, you, *args)
```

*Editor's note: this example appears to be solving a different problem than what is asked about.*

Comment: Can you provide an example of adding a method 'later'?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I assume he's talking about changing the source code alter, not about programatically adding methods.

Comment: @delnan, yes, thats what I meant.

Comment: well, that's a relief, many of these techniques only work with the former, but not the latter.

Comment: I don't get how this can work, as __call__ is only used when the object is called as a function, eg. `ob = MyClass(); ob()`, which doesn't seems to be the case here. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alexis Métaireau, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python on __call__

Comment: In a somewhat similar situation except where only certain methods are to decorated, there's [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21976794/355230).

Comment: @rapadura, Alexis is right. A callable is a callable. It has literally nothing to do with decorating every method in a class.

Comment: Checkout the metaclass approach below for a solution which also caters for subclasses.

Comment: I don't know how is the 'solution' from 'EDIT' supposed to work (in python 3) : /  I have class A with functions f1, f2 ...f10 and decorator 'd1'; how to make all functions decorated?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Decorate the class with a function that walks through the class's attributes and decorates callables. This may be the wrong thing to do if you have class variables that may happen to be callable, and will also decorate nested classes (credits to Sven Marnach for pointing this out) but generally it's a rather clean and simple solution. Example implementation (note that this will not exclude special methods (`__init__` etc.), which may or may not be desired):

```
def for_all_methods(decorator):
    def decorate(cls):
        for attr in cls.__dict__: # there's propably a better way to do this
            if callable(getattr(cls, attr)):
                setattr(cls, attr, decorator(getattr(cls, attr)))
        return cls
    return decorate
```

Use like this:

```
@for_all_methods(mydecorator)
class C(object):
    def m1(self): pass
    def m2(self, x): pass
    ...
```

Comment: "class variables that may happen to be callable"  how is that not a method?

Comment: Note that this will also decorate nested classes.  (My implementation had the same problem.)

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I assume Python would treat it as a method, too. But OP may not consider it a method of the class.

Comment: @Sven: Good catch, although propably negible (nested classes are rare and rarely useful). Added to the answer.

Comment: why not use `inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod)` instead of `__dict__` and `callable()` ? of course  static method will be out of the question in this case.

Comment: @mouad: This is precisely the "better way to do this" I hoped for but couldn't think of.

Comment: what do you think of the mixin approach? the methods Im interested in wraping/decorating with my own code before executing, still do execute and I dont have to "walk" down a class methods and add decorators, simply using __call__ and inheritance.

Comment: @Antonio: I don't see how this mixin would work. Please explain.

Comment: In Python 3 `inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod)` won't work because `inspect.ismethod` returns `False` for unbound methods. In Python 2 `inspect.ismethod` returns `True` for unbound methods but `inspect.isfunction` returns `False`. Maybe it's best to write `inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isroutine)` instead as that works for both.

Comment: With respect to using inspect.getmembers this may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-you-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class

Comment: I'm about to do something similar.  Is this still a good method in 2014?  Could you update your answer to use inspect rather than the `__dict__` stuff?

Comment: Using `cls.__dict__`  would not decorate inherited methods, but the `inspect` approach would.

Comment: I personally wouldn't WANT to decorate inherited methods, if you wanted that wouldn't you decorate the superclass where they were defined?

Answer (score 40):

While I'm not fond of using magical approaches when an explicit approach would do, you can probably use a metaclass for this.

```
def myDecorator(fn):
    fn.foo = 'bar'
    return fn

class myMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, local):
        for attr in local:
            value = local[attr]
            if callable(value):
                local[attr] = myDecorator(value)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, local)

class myClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = myMetaClass
    def baz(self):
        print self.baz.foo
```

and it works as though each callable in `myClass` had been decorated with `myDecorator`

```
>>> quux = myClass()
>>> quux.baz()
bar
```

Comment: Can you comment on the mixin approach?

Comment: Just a caveat: `callable(<class>)` is `True`. This behavior may or may not be desired, depending upon your use case.

Comment: I am also looking into this approach and it's great. Here is a good reference discussing metaclasses in general: https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/ One good point mentioned within this reference is that this approach also takes care of subclasses where as, I believe that class decorators do not. This, to me is an important point!

Comment: I don't think this is magical at all, rather that metaclasses have a bad PR department. They should be used whenever they are suitable, as is the case here. Good solution!

Comment: Notice that for python 3 you should use: `class myClass(metaclass=myMetaClass):`

Answer (score 18):

Not to revive things from the dead, but I really liked delnan's answer, but found it sllliigghhtttlllyy lacking.

```
def for_all_methods(exclude, decorator):
    def decorate(cls):
        for attr in cls.__dict__:
            if callable(getattr(cls, attr)) and attr not in exclude:
                setattr(cls, attr, decorator(getattr(cls, attr)))
        return cls
    return decorate
```

EDIT: fix indenting

So you can specify methods//attributes//stuff you don't want decorated

Comment: Improvements are always welcome, someone may find it useful with time

Answer (score 11):

None of the above answers worked for me, since I wanted to also decorate the inherited methods, which was not accomplished by using `__dict__`, and I did not want to overcomplicate things with metaclasses. Lastly, I am fine with having a solution for Python 2, since I just have an immediate need to add some profiling code for measuring time used by all functions of a class.

```
import inspect
def for_all_methods(decorator):
    def decorate(cls):
        for name, fn in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
            setattr(cls, name, decorator(fn))
        return cls
    return decorate
```

Source (slightly different solution): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467879/1243926
There you can also see how to change it for Python 3.

As comments to other answers suggest, consider using `inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.isroutine)` instead. If you have found a proper solution that works for both Python 2 and Python 3 and decorates inherited methods, and can still be done in 7 lines, please, edit.

Answer (score 5):

You could generate a metaclass. This will not decorate inherited methods.

```
def decorating_meta(decorator):
    class DecoratingMetaclass(type):
        def __new__(self, class_name, bases, namespace):
            for key, value in list(namespace.items()):
                if callable(value):
                    namespace[key] = decorator(value)

            return type.__new__(self, class_name, bases, namespace)

    return DecoratingMetaclass
```

This will generate a metaclass decorating all methods with the specified function. You can use it in Python 2 or 3 by doing something like this

```
def doubling_decorator(f):
    def decorated(*a, **kw):
        return f(*a, **kw) * 2
    return decorated

class Foo(dict):
    __metaclass__ = decorating_meta(doubling_decorator)

    def lookup(self, key):
        return self[key]

d = Foo()
d["bar"] = 5
print(d.lookup("bar")) # prints 10
```