# Decorating a method that's already a classmethod?

Tags: python, decorator, chaining

I had an interesting problem this morning.  I had a base class that looked like this:

```
# base.py
class Base(object):

    @classmethod
    def exists(cls, **kwargs):
        # do some work
        pass
```

And a decorator module that looked like this:

```
# caching.py

# actual caching decorator
def cached(ttl):
    # complicated

def cached_model(ttl=300):
    def closure(model_class):
        # ...
        # eventually:
        exists_decorator = cached(ttl=ttl)
        model_class.exists = exists_decorator(model_class.exists))

        return model_class
    return closure
```

Here's my subclass model:

```
@cached_model(ttl=300)
class Model(Base):
    pass
```

Thing is, when I actually call Model.exists, I get complaints about the wrong number of arguments!  Inspecting the arguments in the decorator shows nothing weird going on - the arguments are exactly what I expect, and they match up with the method signature.  How can I add further decorators to a method that's already decorated with `classmethod`?

Not all models are cached, but the exists() method is present on every model as a classmethod, so re-ordering the decorators isn't an option: `cached_model` can add classmethod to exists(), but then what makes exists() a classmethod on uncached models?

Comment: So, what's the solution? It's not clear. It would have been much better had you left your question as it was, and posted an answer.

Comment: You *can* post a question and answer it yourself, but please keep question and answer separate. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: I think you forgot a `@classmethod` in class `Base`.

Comment: @RikPoggi, asked the explicit question, fixed missing decorator - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `classmethod` decorator actually prepends a `class` argument to calls to the method, in certain circumstances, as far as I can tell, in addition to binding the method to the class.  The solution was editing my class decoration closure:

```
def cached_model(ttl=300):
    def closure(model_class):
        # ...
        # eventually:
        exists_decorator = cached(ttl=ttl, cache_key=exists_cache_key)
        model_class.exists = classmethod(exists_decorator(model_class.exists.im_func))

        return model_class
    return closure
```

The `im_func` property appears to get a reference to the original function, which allows me to reach in and decorate the original function with my caching decorator, and then wrap that whole mess in a `classmethod` call.  Summary, `classmethod` decorations are not stackable, because arguments seem to be injected.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, when a method is declared, in a function body, it is exactly like a function -
once the class is parsed and exists, retrieving the method through the "." operator transforms that function - on the fly - into a method. This transform does add the first parameter to the method (if it  is not an staticmethod) -

so:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    def b(self):
...        pass
... 
>>> A.b is A.b
False
```

Becasue each retrieving of the "b" attribute of "A" yields a different instance of the "method object b"

```
>>> A.b
<unbound method A.b>
```

The original function "b" can be retrieved without any trasnform if one does

```
>>> A.__dict__["b"]
<function b at 0xe36230>
```

For a function decorated with `@classmethod` just the same happens, and the value "class" is added to the parameter list when it is retrieved from A.

The `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` decorators will wrap the underlying function in a different descriptor than the normal instancemethod. A classmethod object - which is what a function becomes when it is wrapped with `classmethod` is a descriptor object, which has a '__get__' method which will return a function wrapping the underlying function - and adding the "cls" parameter before all the other ones.

Any further decorator to a `@classmethod` has to "know" it is actually dealing with a descriptor object, not a function.  -

```
>>> class A(object):
...    @classmethod
...    def b(cls):
...       print b
... 
>>> A.__dict__["b"]
<classmethod object at 0xd97a28>
```

So, it is a lot easier to let the `@classmethod` decorator to be the last one to be applied to the method (the first one on the stack) - so that the other decorators work on a simple function (knowing that the "cls" argument will be inserted as the first one).

Comment: True, but sometimes you don't have control over the order of the decorators.  In my case, the method is always a classmethod, but only some classes have the additional caching decorator - it's subclass-specific.  In that case, you need a way to 'undo' the first classmethod decorator.  See my answer for what I ended up going with.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108205/jsbueno) for the information about Python.  I was looking for an answer to this question based on the case of [decorating all methods of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-can-i-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for).  Based on looking for an answer to this question and jsbueno's reponse, I was able to gather something along the lines of:

```
def for_all_methods(decorator):

    def decorate(cls):

        for attr in dir(cls):
            possible_method = getattr(cls, attr)
            if not callable(possible_method):
                continue

            # staticmethod
            if not hasattr(possible_method, "__self__"):
                raw_function = cls.__dict__[attr].__func__
                decorated_method = decorator(raw_function)
                decorated_method = staticmethod(decorated_method)

            # classmethod
            elif type(possible_method.__self__) == type:
                raw_function = cls.__dict__[attr].__func__
                decorated_method = decorator(raw_function)
                decorated_method = classmethod(decorated_method)

            # instance method
            elif possible_method.__self__ is None:
                decorated_method = decorator(possible_method)

            setattr(cls, attr, decorated_method)

        return cls
    return decorate
```

There's a bit of redundancy and a few variations you could use to chop this down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just a functional example to add to Scott Lobdell's great answer...

*messages.py*

```
from distutils.cmd import Command

import functools
import unittest

def for_all_methods(decorator):

    def decorate(cls):

        for attr in cls.__dict__:
            possible_method = getattr(cls, attr)
            if not callable(possible_method):
                continue

            # staticmethod
            if not hasattr(possible_method, "__self__"):
                raw_function = cls.__dict__[attr].__func__
                decorated_method = decorator(raw_function)
                decorated_method = staticmethod(decorated_method)

            # classmethod
            if type(possible_method.__self__) == type:
                raw_function = cls.__dict__[attr].__func__
                decorated_method = decorator(raw_function)
                decorated_method = classmethod(decorated_method)


            # instance method
            elif possible_method.__self__ is None:
                decorated_method = decorator(possible_method)

            setattr(cls, attr, decorated_method)

        return cls

    return decorate

def add_arguments(func):
    """
    The add_arguments decorator simply add the passed in arguments
    (args and kwargs) the returned error message.
    """    
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            message = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            message = ''.join([message, 
                               "[ args:'", str(args), "'] ", 
                               "[ kwargs:'", str(kwargs), "' ] " 
                               ])
            return message

        except Exception as e:
            err_message = ''.join(["errorhandler.messages.MESSAGE: '",
                                   str(func), 
                                   "(", str(args), str(kwargs), ")' ", 
                                   "FAILED FOR UNKNOWN REASON. ",
                                   " [ ORIGINAL ERROR: ", str(e), " ] "
                                   ])
            return err_message

    return wrapped



@for_all_methods(add_arguments)    
class MESSAGE(object):
    """
            log.error(MSG.triggerPhrase(args, kwargs))

    """    
    @classmethod
    def TEMPLATE(self, *args, **kwargs):
        message = "This is a template of a pre-digested message."
        return message
```

*usage*

```
from messages import MESSAGE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = MESSAGE.TEMPLATE(1,2,test=3)
    print result
```

*output*

```
This is a template of a pre-digested message.[ args:'(1, 2)'] [ kwargs:'{'test': 3}' ]
```