# Error in decorating a classmethod

Tags: python

I was working on a decorator that decorates the class. It woks fine for instance methods but gives an TypeError for class method. The code is as below:

```
def deco_method(fn):
  def wrapper(*arg, **kwarg):
    """
    Function: Wrapper
    """
    print "Calling function {}".format(fn.__name__)
    print arg, kwarg
    ret_val = fn(*arg, **kwarg)
    print "Executed function {}".format(fn.__name__)
    return ret_val
  return wrapper

def clsdeco(cls):
  attributes = cls.__dict__.keys()

  for attribute in attributes:
    # Do not decorate private methods
    if '__' in attribute:
        continue 

    # Get the method
    value = getattr(cls, attribute)
    if not hasattr(value, '__call__'):
        continue

    # CHeck if method is a class method or normal method and decoate accordingly
    if value.im_self is None:# non class method
        setattr(cls, attribute, deco_method(value))
    elif value.im_self is cls: # CHeck if the method is class method 
        setattr(cls, attribute, classmethod(deco_method(value)))
    else: 
        assert False
  return cls # return decorated class



@clsdeco
class Person:
  message = "Hi Man"
  def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
    self.fname = first_name
    self.lname = last_name
    self.age = None

  def get_name(self):
    print "Name is '{} {}'".format(self.fname, self.lname)

  @classmethod
  def greet_person(cls):
     print cls.message

p = Person('John', 'snow')
p.greet_person()
```

It gives an error:

`TypeError: greet_person() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

If i remove @clsdeco, it works perfectly fine.

Any idea what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the line shown it will work. This is because the @classmethod decorator applied in the class definition changes what `getattr(cls, attribute)` returns—it will be a descriptor for the named method which adds the `cls` argument and then calls the real method.

What you need to do is retrieve the "raw" value of the attribute which is just a regular function and then turn it back into a class method by explicitly calling `classmethod`. This needed "raw" value is stored in the class dictionary `__dict__` associated with the same attribute name, hence the need for adding the `value = cls.__dict__[attribute].__func__` line.

Something similar will also be required to handle static methods properly. How to do this for all the different types of methods is described in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31843829/355230) to the question [***Decorating a method that's already a classmethod?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977359/decorating-a-method-thats-already-a-classmethod) Some of the other answers also describe what's going on in more detail than I have here.

```
def clsdeco(cls):
  attributes = cls.__dict__.keys()

  for attribute in attributes:
    # Do not decorate private methods
    if '__' in attribute:
        continue

    # Get the method
    value = getattr(cls, attribute)
    if not hasattr(value, '__call__'):
        continue

    # Check if method is a class method or normal method and decoate accordingly
    if value.im_self is None:# non class method
        setattr(cls, attribute, deco_method(value))
    elif value.im_self is cls: # Check if the method is class method
        value = cls.__dict__[attribute].__func__                        # ADDED
        setattr(cls, attribute, classmethod(deco_method(value)))
    else:
        assert False

  return cls # return decorated class
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice that the getattr returns the descriptors.         "value = cls.__dict__[attribute].__func__" works. Alternatively we can also do   "value = value.im_func" [for python 2.7]     and                                "value = value.__func__" [python 3]

Comment: @Luminos: In Python 2.6 they made `__func__` an alais for `im_func`, so using that would be more portable—but I believe using `cls.__dict__[attribute].__func__` already will work in both Python 2 and 3.