# Write a decorator to apply another decorator with arguments for all methods of a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

Coming from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-can-i-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for). The accepted answer works nicely with decorators which take no argument. I'm trying to extend this solution to make it take arguments for the applying decorator.

In detail, I have functions which make external api calls. Because those calls fail frequently, I applied retry decorator from this [library](https://github.com/rholder/retrying) to all the functions. To avoid putting the `@retry(...)` line again and again for all the functions, I decided to centralize them in a class. I created RetryClass and put all the functions as `classmethod` in the class. Now, I'm looking for a way to apply the `retry` decorator for all the methods of the class, so that I can just keep adding new methods in the class and it will automatically apply the `retry` decorator for the new methods.

**Note:** the retry decorator takes arguments.

```
@retry(wait_random_min=100, wait_random_max=300, stop_max_attempt_number=3)
```

Here is my code:

```
from retrying import retry


def for_all_methods(decorator):
    def decorate(cls):
        for attr in cls.__dict__:
            if callable(getattr(cls, attr)):
                setattr(cls, attr, decorator(getattr(cls, attr)))
        return cls
    return decorate


@for_all_methods(retry(wait_random_min=100, wait_random_max=300, stop_max_attempt_number=3))
class RetryClass(object):

    @classmethod
    def a(cls):
        pass


def test():
    RetryClass.a()
    return
```

This throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/gyoho/Datatron/Dev/class-decorator/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    test()
  File "/Users/gyoho/Datatron/Dev/class-decorator/main.py", line 22, in test
    RetryClass.a()
TypeError: unbound method a() must be called with RetryClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

However, commenting out the class decorator runs with no error. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: When you want to apply it to all methods, you may be better off with a [meta class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python#6581949).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`classmethod` and `staticmethod` must be the last decorator on a method, because they return [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and not a function. (Which are trickier to decorate). You could detect if a method is already a `classmethod` or `staticmethod`, and then your `decorate` function would look somewhat like this:

```
def decorate(cls):
    for attr in cls.__dict__:
        possible_method = getattr(cls, attr)
        if not callable(possible_method):
            continue

        if not hasattr(possible_method, "__self__"):
            raw_function = cls.__dict__[attr].__func__
            decorated_method = decorator(raw_function)
            decorated_method = staticmethod(decorated_method)

        if type(possible_method.__self__) == type:
            raw_function = cls.__dict__[attr].__func__
            decorated_method = decorator(raw_function)
            decorated_method = classmethod(decorated_method)

        elif possible_method.__self__ is None:
            decorated_method = decorator(possible_method)

        setattr(cls, attr, decorated_method)

    return cls
```

Comment: Maybe, it'll be easier just to instantiate an object from the class and use its methods then?

Comment: @gyoho It would possibly be simpler, bur keep in mind you'd still have trouble with `staticmethod` and `property`

Comment: I removed the `@classmethod` and changed `cls` to `self`, but didn't put `@staticmethod`. It runs fine this time. What could be the drawback for doing this?

Comment: The main drawback as I see it is that you might want that functionality in the furture. Also, depending on what your methods do, you might not want to have multiple instances (e.g. multiple database connection)

Comment: I instantiated an object in `__init__.py` and import the object as necessary, so it's like a singleton object. Because the class has no variable, I guess for this particular case it's OK to do this way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `@classmethod` is no longer the top level decorator for `a()`. `RetryClass.a` is currently decorated with both `@classmethod` and `@retry`, in that order. `RetryClass` is equivalent to:

```
class RetryClass(object):

    @retry(wait_random_min=100, wait_random_max=300, stop_max_attempt_number=3)
    @classmethod
    def a(cls):
        pass
```

Your class needs to be equivalent to:

```
class RetryClass(object):

    @classmethod
    @retry(wait_random_min=100, wait_random_max=300, stop_max_attempt_number=3)
    def a(cls):
        pass
```

Comment: I guess I just need to avoid the `classmethod` or `staticmethod` then. Instantiate this class and use its method?