# Is it possible to redefine keywords in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, reserved-words, redefinition

I ran into an issue wherein I had to jsonify everything that my API was set to return. As I was writing a decorator and applying it to every single method, a thought occurred to me:

> "Can't I just overwrite the return keyword so that it performs this operation for me every time?"

I did some searching, but I can't find anything on the topic. However, since "everything is an object", maybe it's possible?

Obviously overwriting `return` is a bad idea but in a more general sense, my question is:

**Can you alter the behavior of reserved words and keywords in Python?**

Comment: Nope.....unless you fork the python project and rewrite the return keyword, will work but only if you want to return json everywhere....lol

Comment: Is it a class? You can decorate all methods in a class with a [single decorator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-can-i-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for)

Comment: @Grant McCloskey I'm not so much trying to solve a specific problem here as gain a better understanding of the language as a whole. I wrote my thought process out so people can understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Yep, I was just trying to think of other alternatives to the origin of the question because I have hit similar.

Comment: I was a little surprised that I couldn't find a duplicate for this question, so I've expanded a little on the comment by @RodrigoAlencar to make it a "proper" answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, you can't redefine reserved words in Python. Their meaning is … *drumroll* … **reserved**, so by definition it cannot be altered.

The closest I can find to an explicit [declaration](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) of this fact in the official documentation is in the Lexical Analysis chapter of the Language Reference (emphasis mine):

> ## 2.3.1. Keywords
>
> The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of the language, and ***cannot be used as ordinary identifiers***. They must be spelled exactly as written here:
>
> ```
> False      await      else       import     pass
> None       break      except     in         raise
> True       class      finally    is         return
> and        continue   for        lambda     try
> as         def        from       nonlocal   while
> assert     del        global     not        with
> async      elif       if         or         yield
> ```

Since keywords cannot be used as ordinary identifiers, they cannot be assigned to, be used as function names in `def` statements, etc.

It's important to understand that it's the fundamental nature of keywords which actually prohibits changes to their meaning, though – that assignment and so on won't work is a consequence of that nature, not the cause of it.