# Is there a way of assigning lambda to a function?

Tags: python, lambda

I need to assign the lambda function to a variable, and use it later in the script for small protection. Is that possible?

For example, I´ll assign the lambda function to a variable named foo:

```
foo = lambda
```

then, when I need it, I would use it this way or another:

```
foo2 = foo x: x*x
```

is this possible?

Comment: What did you try? Please show your code.

Comment: i tried "foo = lambda"

Comment: `lambda` itself is not a function object, it is a keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lambda` is a keyword and not an object. you have to define the function and save that as a variable.

The usage of lambda is quite straightforward though, as you have already done it with the `print`. Try this -

```
foo = lambda x: x.upper()

foo('hello world')
```

```
'HELLO WORLD'
```

---

EDIT: (Based on OPs comments) Here is a [great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52026471/4755954) that talks about why you can't change the keyword `lambda` with a variable name, being a reserved python keyword.

The OP mentioned these reserved keywords in the answer -

```py
False      await      else       import     pass
None       break      except     in         raise
True       class      finally    is         return
and        continue   for        *lambda*     try
as         def        from       nonlocal   while
assert     del        global     not        with
async      elif       if         or         yield
```

Comment: i mean using it like "foo = lambda" and then doing stuff like "foo2 = foo x: x+1"

Comment: lambda is a `keyword` and not an object. you have to define the function and save that as a variable.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal - Precise answer! I suggest you copy your important comment into your answer as well.

Comment: Thanks, edited my answer accordingly with mroe details

Comment: Now I wonder why `finally` and `from` are colored differently ...

Comment: interesting, i changed the code markdown to `python` specifically, and its the same, but this is only on SO. my IDE's dont have this behaviour

Comment: Yeah I had also tried that. And it [doesn't happen in context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p7Dk.png).

Comment: Oh, it's because they're after `class` and `def`.