# How to call a function on every method call of an object

Tags: python-3.x

I have this class :

```
class DieKlass:
    #My attempt using __init__
    def __init__(self): 
        aMethod()


    def hello(self):
        print ("Hello !")
```

---

```
#Some other file
 Def aMethod():
     print ("me !")
```

---

and I want it to result as this on "ob" being instance of DieKlass :

```
ob.hello()
```

result in :

```
me !
Hello !
```

How to call aMethod() on every method call of DieKlass object without calling explicitly aMethod in DieKlass methods bodies ?

Comment: You could hook into [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

Comment: Write a decorator that calls the function, then decorate every method of the class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-to-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for-eac

Comment: @PatrickHaugh This will work, thank you

Comment: @jonrsharpe this only works for attribute, not methods calls ... still, thank you

Comment: Accessing a method is exactly the same as accessing any other attribute, you can return a wrapper the consumer calls through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def aMethod(func):
    def function_wrapper(x):
        print("Me")
        func(x)
    return function_wrapper

class DieKlass:
    @aMethod
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello")
```

More you can find here: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_decorators.php