# Why does this class decorator not decorate?

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper

At a little bit of a loss here. I'm attempting to decorate all methods of a class, and using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-to-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for-eac). I feel like I have all the pieces (see below) yet when I initialize the class/call its methods, nothing happens.

As a toy example, I've got the function decorator

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        return func(*args)
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper
```

and the class decorator

```py
def for_all_methods(decorator):
    import inspect
    def decorate(cls):
        for name, fn in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
            print(name, fn)
            setattr(cls, name, decorator(fn))
        return cls
    return decorate
```

and the toy class

```py
@for_all_methods(my_decorator)
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wheels = 4
        self.price=20000
        self.mileage = 0
    
    def drive(self, miles):
        self.mileage += miles
    
    def depreciate(self):
        self.price-=0.1*self.mileage
```

yet when I initialize the class

```py
c = Car()
```

or call its methods, they aren't decorated. What gives? I feel like I must be missing something trivial.

Comment: Does `print(name, fn)` print the expected result?

Comment: No, but if I call 
`for name, fn in inspect.getmembers(Car(), inspect.ismethod):
    print(name, fn)` 
I get the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

`inspect.ismethod` checks for bound method objects - the kind of thing you get from `Car().drive`, not `Car.drive`. `Car.drive` is a function object.

The code you were looking at was written for Python 2 only. Methods work a bit differently on Python 2.

Comment: Somehow, it works if I change it to `inspect.isfunction`. I still don't entirely understand, since `for name, fn in inspect.getmembers(Car(), inspect.ismethod):
    print(name, fn)`

prints what I would expect.

Comment: @ahalev: `inspect.getmembers(Car(), ...)` is a very different call from `inspect.getmembers(Car, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it works if I change `inspect.ismethod` to `inspect.isfunction`.

I still don't 100% get it, since

```py
for name, fn in inspect.getmembers(Car(), inspect.ismethod):
     print(name, fn)
```

prints

```
__init__ <bound method my_decorator.<locals>.wrapper of <__main__.Car object at 0x7fb577e30cf8>>
depreciate <bound method my_decorator.<locals>.wrapper of <__main__.Car object at 0x7fb577e30cf8>>
drive <bound method my_decorator.<locals>.wrapper of <__main__.Car object at 0x7fb577e30cf8>>
```

as I would expect.

Edit: user2357112 supports Monica clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66070835/why-does-this-class-decorator-not-decorate/66071050#comment116815166_66070953).