# Decorate all functions of a Python class while being able to access the class attributes within the decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, python-class, class-decorator

I've got a class and would like to apply a decorator to all functions within that class without having to add a function decorator to every single function.
I know that there are solutions like the ones explained here [How to decorate all functions of a class without typing it over and over for each method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-to-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for-eac) to add a decorator to the entire class. However, I need to have access to all class attributes within the decorator.

So using the decorator from the other solution like so, I'd need to be able to access all of cls's properties in the f

```
def function_decorator(orig_func):
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Decorating wrapper called for method %s" % orig_func.__name__)
        result = orig_func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return decorator

def class_decorator(decorator):
    def decorate(cls):
        # this doesn't work
        # print(cls.name)
        for attr in cls.__dict__: 
            if callable(getattr(cls, attr)):
                setattr(cls, attr, decorator(getattr(cls, attr)))
        return cls
    return decorate

@class_decorator(function_decorator)
class PersonWithClassDecorator:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name) 

me = PersonWithClassDecorator("Me")
me.print_name()
```

The cls variable is of type <class '**main**.PersonWithClassDecorator'>.

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this? I also looked into metaclasses but ran into the same issue of not being able to access the attributes of my class. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: you could probably leverage the `__getattribute__` of the class itself to do what you want, then you will have access to the `self` of the class

Comment: The way it is defined the `name`  property is not initialized at the stage where you want to access/print it. It's rather an instance than a class property. The class is decorated before you create `PersonWithClassDecorator` so as it is the value of `"Me"` just isn't set yet. Or am I reading it wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

### Alternative 1

As @Nullman suggested, you can move the decorating into the [`__getattribute__`-hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__). This method is called whenever any attibute (including methods) are accessed from an instance of your class.

You can implement `__getattribute__` directly in your class or create a mixin that only contains the decorating.

```py
from typing import Any

class Decorate:
    def __getattribute__(self, item: str) -> Any:
        val = super().__getattribute__(item)
        
        if callable(val):
            print("Name", self.name)  # you can access the instance name here
            return function_decorator(val)
        return val
```

And then inherit from `Decorator`.

`class PersonWithClassDecorator(Decorate): ...`

This simple approach has two downsides:

- the `function_decorator` is hardcoded into the `Decorate` class
- dunder-methods like `__init__`, `__str__` or all the operator hooks are not decorated (internally they are not accessed from the instance, but from the class)

**Note**: if you use `mypy` (you should ;-) ) the `__getattribute__` hook disables the detection of non-existing attributes. To solve this, wrap the `__getattribute__` definition in a `if not typing.TYPE_CHECKING` block.

### Alternative 2

The `function_decorator` actually has access to instance attributes. You can change it accordingly and use your original approach.

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any

def function_decorator(orig_function: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    def decorator(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        print(f"Decorating wrapper called for method {orig_func.__name__}: {self.name}")
        return orig_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

**Note:** i added type hints and replaced the old `%`-based string formatting with `f`-strings.

This has a small problem: `self.name` is only defined **after** `__init__` was called. You can handle this in different ways:

- `getattr(self, 'name', None)` - `self.name` is then `None` before init
- Don't decorate `__init__`: `if orig_func.__name__ == '__init__': return orig_func`
- Use a different decorator for `__init__`

Downsides:

- You will also have to handle `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`
- the `function_decorator` is now coupled to your class