# How to class decorate a class method

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, static, python-decorators

I am using a class decorator for a subclass TestClass which inherits SuperClass. I have a classmethod in SuperClass called what(cls) which takes in a class. I want to be able to decorate that class in my subclass TestClass, but it is not letting me as it is saying.

`TypeError: unbound method wrapper() must be called with TestClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

I have tried to make an instantiation of my TestClass object and then use that to call method `testclass.what(cls)` and that works, but when I do `TestClass.what()`, it gives me the error above.

```py
def class_decorator(cls):
    for attr_name in dir(cls):
        attr_value = getattr(cls, attr_name)
        if hasattr(attr_value, '__call__'):  # check if attr is a function
            # apply the function_decorator to your function
            # and replace the original one with your new one
            setattr(cls, attr_name, ball(attr_value))
    return cls


def ball(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("hello")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper



class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def what(cls):
        print("testing")


@class_decorator
class TestClass(SuperClass):

    def what(cls):
        super().what()


TestClass.what()
```

Expected:

```py
"hello"
"testing"
"hello"
"testing"

Actual: TypeError: unbound method wrapper() must be called with TestClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Comment: It sounds like your local wrapper function needs to take self and pass it to func.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attaching a decorator to all functions within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467526/attaching-a-decorator-to-all-functions-within-a-class)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your program; instead of going to all the details I'm gonna point out the way to get your desired output.

The error is being raised because you've overriden the classmethod `what` in `TestClass`, which now takes a single argument `cls` that cna be anything. In other words, you also need to decorate your classmethod in subclass by using the `classmethod` decorator.

If you want to keep your current code, you need to provide the `cls` argument expilictly, something like following should do:

```
from functools import partial

def class_decorator(cls): 
    for attr_name in vars(cls): 
        attr_value = getattr(cls, attr_name) 
        if callable(attr_value):  # check if attr is a function 
            if attr_name == 'what': 
                setattr(cls, attr_name, partial(ball(attr_value), cls=cls)) 
            else: 
                setattr(cls, attr_name, ball(attr_value))
```

using `partial` to pass in the class as first argument.

Also, I've used `vars(cls)` to get the `cls.__dict__` as `dir` does recursion on bases (which you don't want here). Also, rather than checking for the `__call__` attribute, use `callable`.

Comment: Now it it saying that TestClass is a Nonetype object