# How to decorate all functions and class methods in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For debugging purpose,
want to decorate all functions and
Class methods in a module file
automatically ?

There are some methods for class only,
[Attaching a decorator to all functions within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467526/attaching-a-decorator-to-all-functions-within-a-class)

But to do for all functions, classes.

example of decorator

```
def mydeco(f):
    print(vars)
    time.sleep()
    return f
```

Comment: You can use the code in the question you linked. Just pass in your module instead of the class. You will have to modify it to also call the same code on each object in your module.

Comment: Do you want to do the decoration in the module or do you want to decorate it after importing the module somewhere else?

Comment: XY problem: if you need to examine the runtime environment of a function call, use a debugger.

Comment: In the module at the top. Or best, as imported from external file.

Comment: Want to run the code slowly without manual stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find this solution.
It requires 2 modules:

```
"""module2 module : wrapper to modify object"""

import sys
import importlib

_hackers = []
def register(obj):
    _hackers.append(obj)

class Hacker:
    def hack(self, module):
        return module

class Loader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.module = None
    
    def find_module(self, name, path):
        sys.meta_path.remove(self)
        self.module = importlib.import_module(name)
        sys.meta_path.insert(0, self)
        return self
    
    def load_module(self, name):
        if not self.module:
            raise ImportError("Unable to load module.")
        module = self.module
        for hacker in _hackers:
            module = hacker.hack(module)
        sys.modules[name] = module
        return module

sys.meta_path.insert(0, Loader())





"""decorations module"""

import types
import module2

_modules = {}
_decorators = []
def register(decorator, modules=None):
    """Register a decorator for a list of module names."""
    if not decorator:
        return
    if not modules and decorator in _decorators:
        return
    if not modules:
        _decorators.append(decorator)
        return

    if isinstance(modules, str):
        modules = (modules,)
    for module in modules:
        if module not in _modules:
            _modules[module] = []
        _modules[module].append(decorator)

class One(module2.Hacker):
    def hack(self, module):
        for decorator in _modules.get(module.__name__, ()):
            self.decorate(module, decorator)
        for decorator in _decorators:
            self.decorate(module, decorator)
        return module
    def decorate(self, module, decorator):
        for attr in module.__dict__:
            obj = getattr(module, attr)
            if isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
                setattr(module, attr, decorator(obj))

module2.register(One())
```