# How to add suffix operations for all python functions?

Tags: python, function

I have a a collection of functions inside a file myfile.py and I would like to add a timer print automatically for each of them:
(have around 700 functions)

```py
def myfunXXX() 
   mytime.start()

   mytime.end() 

mytime.start(): to= time.time()
mytime.end():   print(time.time() - t0)
```

Current solutions are :

1. Add a decorator manually to all the functions.
2. Add the code snippet to all the functions

Is there a way to "hack" Python and the function base definition
to add those 2 functions before executing and at execution end
for a set of Python functions ?

Maybe using AST and injecting some string code ?

Comment: What's wrong with a decorator?

Comment: I need to add the decorators to the 500 functions in the code.
Prefer something automatic

Comment: You could probably regex search-and-replace the decorator onto the function declarations.

Comment: I was about to suggest something like that.  Much more preferable than hacking Python's import logic.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to use a normal profiler?

Comment: [python - Viewing all defined variables - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633127/viewing-all-defined-variables) ? Then check which ones are functions and patch.

Comment: You could probably iterate over the functions in the file [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/139198/312407) and create proxy functions. But then you'd have to update the code which uses the functions to pull the functions from the proxy module instead, which might also be a hassle.

Comment: As others suggested, this is a job that a profiler already does. See [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to learn more (in particular about `cProfile`). tl;dr: `python -m cProfile -s cumulative myfile.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sys.setprofile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile) is meant exactly for this.

Make sure you filter according to `frame.f_code.co_filename` to only stop on the wanted files.

On call event start the timer, on return stop.

Make sure you use `time.perf_counter` as the timer. The others are less reliable.

Keep in mind, as any other profiler that checks all functions in a module, especially one written in Python, it will slow down your code.

---

Example:

```
import sys, time


def create_profile_function(filename):
    _active_frames = {}

    def profile_func(frame, event, arg):
        if event == "call" and frame.f_code.co_filename == filename:
            _active_frames[frame] = time.perf_counter()
        elif event == "return" and frame in _active_frames:
            print(frame.f_code.co_name,
                  time.perf_counter() - _active_frames.pop(frame))

    return profile_func

sys.setprofile(create_profile_function(__file__))

def test():
    print("rawr")
    pass

test()
```

Output:

```
rawr
test 0.0005169999785721302
```

Comment: I still doubt they really need such custom profiling code instead of just using an existing profiler, but interesting anyway.

Comment: @KellyBundy he might need modifications or printing on-demand, no clue :-)

Comment: This is not necessary profiling, more getting
the time at exit for a list of 500 functions (from one module .py)

Comment: @quantCode my answer works nonetheless

Comment: thanks,
Can you write a complete and minimal example ?
After will approve.

Comment: @quantCode added.

Comment: sure, thx.
How to execute only on specific function name of the file myfile.py ?

Comment: `frame.f_code.co_filename == "myfile.py" and frame.f_code.co_name == "func"`

Answer (score -1):

One solution if you're willing to modify where you call these functions is to do something like this:

```
import time
def wrapper(function,args):
    start = time.time()
    function(args)
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
```

I know you don't want to add decorators because you have a lot of functions to add them to. If you're willing to put your functions in a class you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307761/how-to-decorate-all-functions-of-a-class-without-typing-it-over-and-over-for-eac) answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467526/attaching-a-decorator-to-all-functions-within-a-class) answer useful on automatically adding decorators to classes.

Answer (score -1):

Decorators that **Patch Classes** is one "hack" that comes to mind.

```py
def _task(cls):
   og_attrs = cls.__getattribute__
   def new_getattrs(self, name):
       return og_attrs(self, name)
   cls.__getattribute__ = new_getattrs
   return cls 

@_task # mass change in class method's behavior
class A:
    def reborn_function(self):
        pass
```

Your whole issue might not go away at once. But this is the closest thing you have to be backward compatible and elegant. Ast will be a wrong move if you are worried about API changes or backward compatibility.